# Would it be correct to say that "whose" is "the only interrogative possessive pronoun"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, possessives

I am creating a crossword puzzle for submission to a newspaper. For the entry WHOSE, would it be correct to say "The only interrogative possessive pronoun" as the clue? Would pedantic solvers approve or complain?

Comment: Can't *His?* and *Hers?* and *Theirs?* be Interrogative possessive pronouns?

Comment: @nnnnnn I think the question is asking about equivalents to ***Whose*** *is it?* I can't see formulating a similar question with any of the pronouns you suggest. Well, perhaps something like ***His*** *is green?* but that seems uncommon. Still, the clue would have to be clarified to exclude that in some way.

Comment: Then again, just change **the only** to **an** in the clue, and only one pronoun will work within the context of the surrounding letters anyway. It won't matter if there are other pronouns.

Comment: The problem is that Interrogative "whose", in for example "Whose hat is this?" is not a pronoun but a determinative (or determiner for some).

Comment: Sounds like it belongs to the Doctor – but to whom does it belong?

Comment: Pedantic solvers will be quick to point out that a clue is supposed to be *a clue*. Meaning to say, there is no reason whatsoever at all for the words "the only" to be there in the first place. The whole point of a crosswords puzzle is that any one clue could easily apply to more than one word, so you have to *find* the correct one. Otherwise it's not a puzzle, but a dictionary. "A city in Europe" is a puzzle. "The current capital of Russia" is not.

Comment: I don't think Alex is interested in any of these comments.

Comment: Yes, _whose_ is the only possessive interrogative pronoun. And it's not restricted to human antecedents; if you need a possessive, you can use it. _The house whose roof blew off, a book whose title page is missing, ..._

Comment: But it's not a pronoun -- it's a determinative (or determiner). It can't be a pronoun because interrogative pronouns don't function as dependents in NP structure. Both major dictionaries get it right: [link](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whose) / [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/whose). Even without a following noun, as in "Whose is this?" it's still a determinative -- in a fused determiner-head NP.

Comment: @BillJ - My copy of Webster's New Collegiate Dictionary (1973) only lists "whose" as an adjective or pronoun.

Comment: @HotLicks That's because M-W are light years behind current thinking. Even the conservative Oxford calls the dependent kind a determiner, and has done for many years.

Comment: It's called a pronoun. That's a term that's on The List. _Determinative_ isn't. Even for linguists. It's true that M-W is light-years behind, but CGEL is on a different wavelength and only a few are tuned in.